# When does a Sefer Torah become a Sefer Torah?

Tags: sefer-torah, safrus

According to [this](http://www.dailyhalacha.com/m/halacha.aspx?id=873) site, there is practice to accord to a Sefer Torah certain separateness and to refrain from touching it. On [this](http://www.myjewishlearning.com/article/torah-scroll/2/) page, there is a picture of a scribe who is writing the text and it looks like he is touching the parchment.

At what point in the creation/writing process does the Sefer Torah become an actual Torah that would require that it not be touched? Is it when the Sofer starts writing it (or putting sirtutim on it), and he isn't touching it in that picture, or when the last letter is completed, or some other moment?

Comment: +1, you can add, if the sefer Torah become pasul and the scribe need to repair it, is he allowed to touch it? But it is not a question, when the ST need to be repaired. So, despit the that the question is great, the argument of the scribe is not a proof.

Comment: a sefer Torah only gets kedusha when its complete,and of it becomes pasul it still has kedusha and needs genizah,however a Torah scroll which was written incorrectly using the wrong klaf ,ink,sinews etc...then the Torah never gained kedusha (see the Rambam) so a new written Torah cannot gain kedusha until all the letters are comoleted,until the very last letter...will try and investigate more

Comment: if one letter is left and the sefer falls, does one have to fast?

Comment: why would they have to fast if ot was never a kosher sefer Torah

Comment: I'll see if I can ask my local sofer. It's a great question. My thinking, a Torah is pasul if it is missing even one letter, right? So, I think a pasul Torah can be touched on its parchment (have to check this). Thus, logically thinking, it's not a true usable sefer Torah until the last letter is written.